# Unintentionally committed sins

Tags: allah

Salaam Sir!Since I'm getting close to Allah sometimes I say somethings that will make Allah sad , I don't have intention of saying it but I say those words, can u tell me why this happen and second is I have committed shrik unintentionally , I didn't said those words on purpose  but it just slip from my mouth and after saying those words. I try not to commit shrik again but everytime it just come from my mouth unintentionally. I have made a dua but I wanted to ask if Allah will forgive me after saying those words everytime?I don't know why these kind of things comes to my mind after I'm getting close to Allah. I hope you will help me out
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all, whatever you do, Allah (The Exalted) is above all. Allah (subhanu ta'ala) will not be sorry at all for any of your actions or words.

> Glory to Him! He is high above all that they say!- Exalted and Great
> (beyond measure)! - 17:43

Second of all, It is quite natural that a nominal Muslim will not be affected in the same way that a believing Muslim will be attacked by Satan.Since you want to return to Allah (the Almighty), satan has begun to apply his tactics (bad thoughts (which isn't actually a sin), doubtful, depression, confusion, disappointment etc.) to you. So don’t worry about what's going on your mind. Let it be. Don’t take it seriously. Saytaan is whispering at your mind to distract you from your actual goal. Learn  saytaan's tricks and use them against him. It is completely the work of the devil. He is trying to take you away from Islam! He is doing all this with your permission. And you are giving him that approval by showing attention and enthusiasm in his work. So you must not help saytaan by showing your attention at his tricks if you want to get rid of this problem. Patiently pray to Allah (the Almighty) for help..

With regard to what you say about the waswas reaching such a great level that you have begun to experience waswas that makes you think about Allah in ways that are not appropriate, these are evil whispers from the Shaytan. Allah says in glorious Quran:

> **And if there comes to you from Satan an evil suggestion, then seek refuge in Allah. Indeed, He is the Hearing, the Knowing. (Fussilat
> 41:36)**

Lastly, say, “***Amantu Billahi wa Rasoolihi*** (I believe in Allah and His Messenger),” if you feel that you are being affected by this waswas. And ***Try to stop thinking about that*** as much as possible, and keep busy with things that will distract you from it and ***keep on turning to Allah*** in all situations, and to ask Him for help, and to beseech Him, and to ask Him to make you steadfast until death, and to cause you to die doing righteous deed.

Wallahu 'alam

Comment: Firstly jazakallah, I'm glad that you answered but will Allah forgave me for it , if I seek forgiveness with whole heart and I'm reciting this dua to stay away from shirk             اللّهُـمَّ إِنّـي أَعـوذُبِكَ أَنْ أُشْـرِكَ بِكَ وَأَنا أَعْـلَمْ، وَأَسْتَـغْفِرُكَ لِما لا أَعْـلَم